# Show that in Lebesgue theory $\int_\mathbb{R^2} f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}) dxdy = 2 \pi \int_0^\infty r f(r) dr$

Tags: integration, measure-theory, solution-verification

We want to show for any nonnegative integrable $f$ $\int_\mathbb{R^2} f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}) dxdy = 2 \pi \int_0^\infty r f(r) dr$ (without Jacobian formula). This has probably been asked before but I want to check my solution is right before looking at spoilers.

I will show the equality holds for simple functions of the form $f(x)=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k1_{A_k}(x)$. Then by monotone convergence theorem we're done.

Open $\epsilon$ balls generate the Borel sets on $\mathbb{R^2}$ so it suffices to check for $A_k$ of this form wlog centered at the origin (translation invariance). Indeed, for one reason or another, for a disc $A$ radius $R$,
$$\int_{\mathbb{R^2}}1_A dxdy=\text{Area}=\pi R^2=\int_0^R 2\pi r =\int_0^\infty 2\pi r 1_A dr$$
So by linearity we have the property for all simple functions. Done.

I am worried maybe "Area" isn't rigorous enough (for a measure theory class), but the argument seems correct, can I rephrase it in a more convincing way?

Comment: The integrals in both sides are not necessarily invariant under the translation of $f$. However, considering the case $f(r)=\mathbf{1}_{B(0,R)}(r)$ is a good place to start with. Then you may invoke the monotone class theorem. Also, note that area in the plane is just another name for the two-dimensional Lebesgue measure, so I would not worry about using that term.

Comment: @SangchulLee Does it actually matter since the $f$ in the statement is radially symmetric about the origin, so we only need to consider symmetric simple functions?

Comment: I made a mistake in my previous comment, which actually shares a similar issue with your comment. Note that it doesn't make sense to say '$f$ is radially symmetric', since $f$ is just a function from $[0, \infty)$ to $[0, \infty)$. (It is true that $f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ is radially symmetric, though.) So the integral on the left-hand side will be invariant under translation on $f(\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$, but it will not be invariant under translation on $f$ itself. In the same spirit, the indicator function mentioned in my previous comment should be $f(r)=\mathbf{1}_{[0,R)}(r)$.